# What's the use of the [dlms] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

I just noticed the [dlms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dlms) tag. It has only 5 questions which have 7 answers altogether; and just one accepted answer. Needless to say, it hasn't been active for a while.

Moreover, while the tag is about a communication protocol, but most questions are more focused on the [gurux library](https://github.com/Gurux) and not the protocol itself. I think this makes it a pretty good candidate for burnination.

Comment: But the tag has 13 watchers. Wouldn't experts now be deprived from receiving notifications for that small niche they happen to be *the* expert in and they are happy to answer those few questions when they arrive? None of the arguments you use to support burnination seem valid, reasonable or would even needed to be considered if a burn is needed.

Comment: There are [4 criteria required for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070/4099593), and the one which you mention is not one of them. Please [edit] the post, and mention how the burnination request satisfies all the 4 of them.

Comment: @rene Although I am not one of the watchers, I happen to be an expert in that area (well, sort of). And I think the DLMS protocol itself has little to do with the scope of this site. As far as I know, there is only one free/open-source _implementation_ of this protocol by Gurux. IMHO this tag name is misleading. Maybe I wasn't successful in making my point.

Comment: Maybe propose in that case to create a tag for the gurux library, if that doesn't already exist, and then add that tag, maybe make them a synonym later on.

Comment: @rene Is creating that tag something we need community buy-in on or could one of us just take care of it if we have the time.

Comment: @BSMP if you have the privilege you can create it. You only find me again on your path if that tag end-up being wildly misused causing all kind of low-quality stuff being posted.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with this request. This tag is on-topic, describes the content of the question, and is completely unambiguous. It even has a well-written tag Wiki that's very specific about when you should use the tag.

The fact that the tag isn't used very frequently doesn't mean that we should burninate it.

Comment: "This tag is on-topic" care to elaborate? OP claims to be an expert on the protocol and says the opposite,

Comment: @Braiam I don't follow the OP's point, actually - it appears to be an actual software protocol (the OP even admits that there's an open-source implementation of it), so I'm not sure why it *wouldn't* be on-topic here.

Comment: IEEE 11073 is also a protocol, which I know well, and I assure you, the day that it will be ever on topic, be afraid, very afraid. So, I don't buy your argument that because it's a protocol it automatically makes it on topic.